# I want to rotate(3d) svg <path> element eg .cars tier in svg.can it possible?

Tags: svg

Svg source code(car`s Tier) 
This is the  of a cars Tier and i want to rotate it 360 degree.Please Help me..!

```html
<svg id="octocat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="880px" height="500px" viewBox="200 100 259 785" style="fill:#000000;stroke: #000; stroke-opacity:0.5">



<g i:extraneous="self">
 <rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E_" x="25" y="376" fill="none" width="370" height="179"/>
 <g>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
<path class="Tiers" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M-104.577,448.995c56.009,0.229,100.2,42.714,101.4,97.454c1.246,56.84-42.531,98.123-91.49,101.636
                c-62.914,4.515-103.152-44.328-107.193-88.244c-2.873-31.223,6.157-58.2,27.881-80.679
                C-154.761,459.278-130.841,449.813-104.577,448.995z M-103.31,626.189c39.698,0.926,78.677-30.209,78.19-78.934
                c-0.411-41.153-32.875-76.105-77.887-76.017c-44.221,0.087-76.996,34.386-77.513,76.561
                C-181.075,593.027-144.647,626.601-103.31,626.189z"/>
```

Comment: If you rotate something 360 degrees it looks just the same, so you don't need to do anything (other than make the question make sense of course).

Comment: Sir,i have a car`s svg.where i wamt to rotate the car on mouse drag or automatic..!
any suggestions?